# Passing dataframe from PostgresOperator to PythonOperator in Airflow 2.5

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x

In summary, I am using Airflow 2.5 and I would like to have a task to query Postgres table and pass the result of this query to a python task for further result processing, where the pythong function iterates through the result set.

I have been looking at these examples for reference:
https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/dynamic-tasks

Because I want to create a python task for each individual record that I will fetch from the Postgres database.

So the Dag should:

1. Get Config file from directory
2. From config file create list if SQLs
3. Run each SQL in POstgres and return result (postgres dynamic tasks created from 3)
4. From result of each SQL craete Airflow python dynamic task

This is my unfinished DAG. The error I am getting is

TypeError: too many positional arguments

```
import requests
import os, json
import logging
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.postgres.operators.postgres import PostgresOperator
from airflow.hooks.postgres_hook import PostgresHook
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow import XComArg

BASE_DIR = Variable.get("BASE_DIR")
log: logging.log = logging.getLogger("airflow")

DEFAULT_ARGS = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2022, 12, 16),
    'email': [''],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1)
}


def parse_columns(arr):
    # initialize an empty string
    str1 = ","
    if isinstance(arr, dict):
        return (str1.join(arr.keys()))

@task
def generate_sql_queries():
    config_filepath = f"{BASE_DIR}/sd/retl/map/"
    queries = []

    for filename in os.listdir(config_filepath):
        with open(config_filepath + filename) as f:
            config = json.load(f)
            cols = parse_columns(config['properties_map'])
            #logging.info(config['source_stream']['name'])
            query = f"SELECT {cols} FROM {config['source_stream']['schema']}.{config['source_stream']['name']}"
            queries.append(query)
    return queries

@task
def get_data(config):

    pg_hook = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id='DWH_PROD')
    df = pg_hook.get_pandas_df(sql=sql)
    print(df['email'])

@task
def push_data(op_args):
    logging.info(op_args)

with DAG(
        dag_id='SD_rETL',
        default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
        schedule_interval='@daily',
        start_date=datetime(year=2022, month=2, day=1),
        catchup=False
) as dag:

    queries = generate_sql_queries()

    task_get_data = PostgresOperator.partial(
        task_id='Get_Data',
        postgres_conn_id='DWH_PROD'
    ).expand(sql=queries)

    task_push_data = PythonOperator.partial(
        task_id="Push_Data",
        python_callable=push_data
    ).expand(
        op_args=XComArg(task_get_data)
    )




task_get_data>>task_push_data
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the `generate_sql_queries` function as it is not having any input to handle the default input - context.
Please add detailed error log for more reference.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).